# node wait exec to finish and only then call the next exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, readline, child-process

I have 2 files one(readlines.js) is a script that read file lines row by row and the second(test.txt) file contain the lines that the script should execute 
like:

> node /usr/local/server/test/CLI-test.js functionName
>   ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ARG4 ARG5

only after this code is finish I want to read the next line in test.txt
but its seems that all operation execution in the same time .

this is my code in readlines.js

```
var fs = require('fs'), readline = require('readline');
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
var fileTest = process.argv[2] != "" ? './test/'+process.argv[2] : './test/test.txt'; 
var rd = readline.createInterface({
       input: fs.createReadStream(fileTest),
       output: process.stdout,
       console: false
});
rd.on('line', function(line) {
    console.log(line);
    executeCommand(line);
});
function executeCommand(line){
  exec('sudo ' + line,{maxBuffer: 1024 * 500000000}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${err}`);
    return;
  }
    console.log(`Number of files ${stdout}`);
  });
}
```

moreover I found out that all operations happen all together because the buffer was not big enough.

Comment: exec is asyncrhonous?

Comment: yes its asyncrhonous

Comment: well, your code doesn't account for that at all

Comment: I know this way I ask for help!

Comment: oh, so you don't know how to work with asynchronous code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call